# Hiding rows in a table HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, rows, server-side

I have a table in HTML that gets populated with data. However if some of the data is not filled in - which it isn't always, then the table will display, but with empty rows. I'm trying to get these rows that are empty to be hidden. I've tried a few things and nothing has seemed to work as of yet, does anybody have any ideas?

Here is my HTML code for the table:

```
    <table style= width: 1300px;" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 75px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:              16px;">Sample Number</span></td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Sample Type</span></td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Pump No</span></td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Cowl No</span></td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 200px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Sample Location</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Sampling Times</span></td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Duration (mins)</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Flow
    Rates (l/min)</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mean<br>
   Flow Rate (l/min)</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:     16px;">Sample Volume (litres)</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Fibres Counted</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Graticule Fields</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Limit of Detection (f/ml)</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Calculated Result (f/ml)</span></td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Recorded Result (f/ml)</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Start</span></td>
   <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Finish</span></td>
   <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Start</span></td>
   <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Finish</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleNumber_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%TypeofTest_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%PumpNo_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%CowlNo_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleLocation_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleStart_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleFinish_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleDuration_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRateStart_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRateFinish_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRatelminMean_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleVolumelitres_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FibresCount_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%GraticuleFields_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%Limit_1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%CalculatedResult_m1%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%ReportedResult_1%></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleNumber_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%TypeofTest_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%PumpNo_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%CowlNo_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleLocation_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleStart_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleFinish_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleDuration_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRateStart_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRateFinish_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRatelminMean_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleVolumelitres_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FibresCount_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%GraticuleFields_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%Limit_2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%CalculatedResult_m2%></span></td>
   <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%ReportedResult_2%></span></td>
   </tr>
```

For example, imagine only the first row was filled in and the second therefore not need be displayed.

***Edit***

The table gets populated using a mobile application, which you insert data into. The HTML is then a template so that it can be printed. To get this information from the app, you must put in the <% ... %> tags, the stuff inside the tag is the ID of a text-box within the app, for example. If you load this into a web browser it will only display the tags, if this is loaded in the mobile app, it will display information in the table. However if these text-boxes or drop-downs (whatever they may be) haven't been filled in then the table will still load, but with no data in it. I therefore need the blank rows with no data in, to be hidden.

**Here is a link to my table and how it displays**

http://screenpresso.com/=5xMwd The first image is how it displays within a browser and will always show the tag. However the second image is within the app and will show the data that the text boxes have in them, as mentioned above. As you can see if the text-boxes are blank there is blank rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you populate your table?

Comment: Use jQuery to hide() or show() rows.

Comment: @YorickdeWid no, hiding things in jQuery is not a solution!

Comment: try `tr:empty { display:none; }`

Comment: Why not an option? You tagged your post with `jQuery` and you sad "get these rows that are empty to be hidden"

Comment: Anyway, you can see my solution, so now you see, what rows are empty, so you can do with anything with that.

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet: unluckily they are not empty, it has span tags with empty values.

Comment: True.. well, best way to control this is not to hide empty tables but don't print them at all...

Comment: @lolka_bolka because hiding something unwanted instead of not producing it in the first place is quick and dirty workaround. OP should try to fix the way the markup is produced.

Comment: But in this case there is nothing to do with jQuery or any other what he tagged. It should be done on server side, checking all the values of his variables, and if one of them is not empty then show the row, if not, then no producing it.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Hi, I've tried that, it didn't work. I think it is just loading "blank" data in and are not "truly" empty, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b7pexhh6/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
table, table td {border: 1px solid #f00; height: 20px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $('#start').click(function() {
        var rows = $('table').find('tr');
        $.each(rows, function(idx, trobj) {
            var hasvalue = false;
            var spans = $(this).find('td span');
            $.each(spans, function(spanidx, spanobj) {
                //console.log($(obj).html() );
                if ($(spanobj).html() != '') {
                    hasvalue = true;
                }
            });
            if (!hasvalue) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

**Test HTML**

```
<table style= "width: 1300px; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 75px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:              16px;">Sample Number</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Sample Type</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Pump No</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Cowl No</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 200px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Sample Location</span></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Sampling Times</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Duration (mins)</span></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Flow
                Rates (l/min)</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mean<br>
                Flow Rate (l/min)</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:     16px;">Sample Volume (litres)</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Fibres Counted</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Graticule Fields</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Limit of Detection (f/ml)</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Calculated Result (f/ml)</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Recorded Result (f/ml)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Start</span></td>
        <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Finish</span></td>
        <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Start</span></td>
        <td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Finish</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleNumber_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%TypeofTest_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%PumpNo_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%CowlNo_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleLocation_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleStart_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleFinish_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleDuration_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRateStart_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRateFinish_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FlowRatelminMean_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%SampleVolumelitres_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%FibresCount_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%GraticuleFields_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%Limit_1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%CalculatedResult_m1%></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"><%ReportedResult_1%></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: 16px;"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="start">START</button>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, so based on OP edit, this is another jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7pexhh6/8/

Comment: This didn't seem to work in my HTML. I can't have a button click, it needs to be straight away, as it's being loaded as a template for mobile printing. I removed the button click part, but I'm not sure I implemented it correctly?

Comment: This is the code I put in the <head>
`<html><head><title></title>
<script>
function() {
  var rows = $('table').find('tr');
  $.each(rows, function(idx, trobj) {
   var hasvalue = false;
   var spans = $(this).find('td span');
   $.each(spans, function(spanidx, spanobj) {
                   //console.log($(obj).html() );
    if ($(spanobj).html() != '') {
     hasvalue = true;
    }
   });
   if (!hasvalue) {
    $(this).hide();
   }
  });
 });
</script>
</head>`

Comment: I've add the button only for demonstration. If i do not add the button, empty row is automatically hide, so maybe you think, this code is not working. You just have to remove the `$('#start').click(function() {` and its closing `}`, and empty rows wont show.

Comment: I've removed the parts of code as you have suggested above, however it's still displaying the "empty rows". 

 `var rows = $('table').find('tr');
        $.each(rows, function(idx, trobj) {
            var hasvalue = false;
            var spans = $(this).find('td span');
            $.each(spans, function(spanidx, spanobj) {
                //console.log($(obj).html() );
                if ($(spanobj).html() != '') {
                    hasvalue = true;
                }
            });
            if (!hasvalue) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });`

Comment: Hi, I have the same code, however mine has the tags in the second row, where as yours doesn't. Mine could be loading in "Blank" data, would this had an effect?

Comment: The condition is: `$(spanobj).html() != ''` lets consolog.log that, so you can see, what is inside your span.

Comment: But all the rows has values in it. So do you want, if a row has `<%SampleNumber_2%>` value that should be hidden? I mean, if `<%SampleNumber_2%>` has value `57` and `57` is there that is "not empty" but if `<%SampleNumber_2%>` it means "empty" ?

Comment: I can't do a console.log as I have to use this HTML template from a Samsung Tablet.

Comment: Yes what you mentioned above is almost there. I need to display the row if there is data in it, and if say `<%SampleNumber_2%>` has a blank value, it needs to be hidden. (I know it's a bit confusing as I'm using an app etc).

Comment: I hope this link helps. [link](http://screenpresso.com/=5xMwd) The first image is how it is seen within a web browser with the tags, the second is how it is then uploaded on the app. As you can see the first row is populated with data, and the others are blank and must be hidden.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not how I want it. It always needs to include the tags within the table, but it displays different within the app. http://screenpresso.com/=5xMwd please see the link.

Comment: Ok, so now i really do not know, what you want to achive I showed you some examples, from this point, try to do yourself. You can console.log in table too, install firefox and firebug.